# VB.Net loop through each Parameter in SQL Command and Log Name + Value

Tags: vb.net, logging, sqlcommand

I can loop through each Parameter in SQL Command but how do I log 
the parametername and Value?

```
Public  Sub LogParams(sqlcmd As SqlCommand)
        Dim strParam As String = ""
        For Each p As SqlParameter In sqlcmd.Parameters
             strParam +=      'how to get Name and Value of parameter?
        Next p
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't even need to do any research; just use the Visual Studio help!! Type `p.` and see the suggestions.

Comment: stared myself blind into the watch on the sqlcmd.parameters. feel like an idiot. thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as

```
For Each p As SqlParameter In sqlcmd.Parameters
    'p.ParameterName
    'p.Vaalue
Next p
```